# flask-slack-app-slash-command-Function executes if we click the button too

Tags: python, flask, slack, zappa

Slash command is /actions whenever I post this n channel ,a message with button should be posted.
This is working correctly.
But if I click the button to open dialog or submit the dialog **again message with button gets posted**.
And I am not calling the post function during this too.
I am calling it under route /actions
**Code:**

```
@app.route("/actions", methods=["POST"])
def actions():
    a = send_menu()
    #prefix = "payload="    
    data = request.get_data(a)
```

**Should Execute: Only when /actions slash command is used
Should Not: When a button from below function is clicked**
Question: How can I achieve to stop this?

**Below function that executes unnecessarily**

```
def send_menu():
    try:
        response1 = standup_menu_block()
        post_response = requests.post(webhook_url, json={
                'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
                'blocks': response1,
            }
        )
        return post_response
```

***This function will post a message and a button

Steps:
1./actions is input in channel
2.triggers send_menu() and post a message with a button
3.Now if I click that button again the message is posted and dialog is opened

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what you are telling it to do. See this shell session:

```py
>>> def x():
...     print('i was not meant to be printed')
...     return 1
...
>>> z = x()
i was not meant to be printed
>>> z
1
>>>
```

assigning `x()` to `z` caused the function body (here the print statement) to execute.

Same is happening with:

`a = send_menu()`

which is causing this block:

```py
post_response = requests.post(webhook_url, json={
                'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
                'blocks': response1,
            }
        )
```

to get executed.

Comment: Yes but when I click a button from that post function only slack dialog should be opened,in my case again the message is posted...I guess /actions is passing for button operation too...So I need to stop this..Kindly check my steps